# Contador com numero float

Tags: c, float, contador

Pessoal sou novo em programação C. Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo adicionar números float com um contador i, que seria inteiro, qual a melhor solução?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  float nota[4];
  int i;

for(i=0; i<4; i++){
  printf("Digite a nota posição %d", i);
  scanf("%f", nota[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  printf("A nota posição %d  é = %.2f\n",i, nota[i]);
}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por que vc quer colocar float dentro de um contador?

Comment: O que significa "não estou conseguindo"? O programa não compila? Não funciona? Mostra valores diferentes do esperado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema está no `scanf`, algumas IDE até monstram essa linha sublinhada, com um warning, pois como você está enviando uma variável float ao mesmo, você precisa enviar a mesma via referência. Para isso, você utiliza do &:

```
scanf("%f", &nota[i]);
```

Só de alterar essa linha, seu código funcionará e os valores digitados serão inseridos no array corretamente.

---

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/ShockingCrowdedRoutine

Comment: Realmente meu problema estava no &, muito obrigado pela ajuda